# Yeoman copy function doesn't work after prompting

Tags: javascript, yeoman

i am fiddleing around with yeoman and want to write my first generator for a simple html5 boilerplate. My problem is, that the two functions in my generator work well on their own but not together and i don't know why. I checked some generators from the yeoman page, but i don't see what i am doing wrong. I hope you can help me. This is my code:

```
'use strict';
var generators = require('yeoman-generator');
var yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({

  initializing: function(){
    this.log(yosay("\'Allo \'allo I will create your HTML5 Boilerplate..."));
  },

  prompting: function() {
    var done = this.async();
    this.prompt({
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'Your project name',
      //Defaults to the project's folder name if the input is skipped
      default: this.appname
    }, function(answers) {

      this.props = answers
      this.log(answers.name);
      done();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  writing: function(){
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('_page/_index.html'),
      this.destinationPath('index.html'),
      { title: "answers.name" }
    );
  },
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Promises version of the prompting function, as shown on [yeoman.io](http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html).

**Example:**

```
prompting: function() {
    return this.prompt({
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'Your project name',
      //Defaults to the project's folder name if the input is skipped
      default: this.appname
    }).then(function(answers) {
      this.props = answers
      this.log(answers.name);
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

Changes:

1. add `return` before `this.prompt()`.
2. change `this.prompt(prompts, callback);` to `this.prompt(prompts).then(callback);`

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working :-( ... the console gives an error "Object [object Object] has no method 'then' " ... i've tried to update the yeoman generator but the error remains. I am not so much used to promises but why are the other generators working that does'nt use promises?

Comment: The old syntax, without the promises, still works—it just might be more unreliable than the newer method. To get a better idea of what's going on, you might try logging `this` to the console—`this` should refer to the entire generator object. If it doesn't, that's probably the source of your problem.